# What does $\vdash s \rightarrow (\neg s\rightarrow t)$ mean?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

What does this statement mean $\vdash s \rightarrow (\neg s\rightarrow t)$?

And how can I prove it?

Comment: What did you try? what do you know?

Comment: @wece I know and understand `A -> B, B -> C |- A -> C`. But what the hell happens where there's nothing on the left

Comment: There is nothing on the left because your statement is always true. It don't need to have a context to be proved

Comment: That $s\rightarrow(\lnot s\rightarrow t)$ is **true** is a short truth table computation. How one **proves it** is heavily dependent on the axioms, rules of inference chosen by your instructor or book. There are many equivalent but different-looking formulations of logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing $T\vdash\varphi$ means that if we assume $T$ then we can prove $\varphi$. If $T$ is omitted then this means that without any assumptions we can prove $\varphi$, that is to say that $\varphi$ is logically true.

In this case it means that $s\rightarrow(\lnot s\rightarrow t)$ is true, regardless to the truth values of $s$ and $t$.

I'll leave you with the task that this statement is indeed true, but I'm going to give you a small hint:

**Hint:** Use the truth table of $\rightarrow$ and calculate the possible truth values of the statement based on the possible combinations of truth values of $s$ and $t$.

Comment: The trouble with truth tables is that they obscure the precise features of logic that lead to the result. In this case, the statement holds in classical and intuitionistic logics, but not necessarily in a paraconsistent logic. Most people don't care about paraconsistent logic, but it can be useful to know whether a certain result holds intuitionistically.